# Want to auto fill across columns in Excel so that column number skips 2 each time

Tags: excel

I want to be able to auto fill cells such that cell L3 contains the formula `=T3-U3`, cell M3, `=V3-W3`, cell N3, `=X3-Y3`, cell O3 `=Z3-AA3`, etc.

I've spent hours looking through every `offset` and `indirect` tutorial going and I just can't figure it out.

The closest I've got (for `L3`, say) is

```
=offset(R3,,COLUMN()+2,1,1)-offset(S3,,COLUMN()+2,1,1)
```

I think I want to use `COLUMN()*2` somehow but, firstly, I don't understand the point of the reference cell if we're using 'COLUMN()', and secondly, I don't really understand what quantity is being multiplied by 2.

Comment: Could you clarify the relationship between the columns you're looking at? For people like me who grew up with a different alphabet than the English one, the relation between them isn't immediately clear.

Comment: ok, sorry it was unclear.  I'll bear that in mind if I ask questions in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=OFFSET($T3,,2*(COLUMN()-11)-2)-OFFSET($T3,,2*(COLUMN()-11)-1)
```

This anchors the reference point as the `T` column and adds an offset of `-11` for a formula to be entered in the twelfth column (ie `L`).

`COLUMN()` is the reference number for the location (`A`=`1`, `B`=`2`, etc) and in Column L that is `12`. We are interested in skipping to the column after the next (`+2`), so we take the offset (`11`) off of the column number we are in (`12`), then double that.

Comment: I'm just as bad -- all I did was reformat yours a little.

Comment: @pnuts congrats on the gold badge! Just realised this from a duplicate you'd closed.

Comment: @pnuts Ýou earned it in your own right. On that other q, I hadnt voted dupe, I had closed for another reason - your hammer :). And bed time it is

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it works in my spreadsheet.  now I've got a working formula I'm sure I'll figure out each part